# How to map hashfunction output to bloomfilter indices?

Tags: c++, database, algorithm, bloom-filter

Can anyone help me by providing an outline on how the hash function output is mapped to bloom filter indices? Here is an overview on [bloomfilters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> an outline on how the hash function output is mapped to a bloom filter indices

For each of the *k* hash functions in use, they map onto a bit in the bloom filter just as hashes map onto hash buckets in a hash table.  So, very commonly you might have say a hash function generating 32 bit integers, then use the modulus `%` operator to get a bit index `0 << i < n` where `n` is the number of bits in your bloom filter.

To make this very concrete, let's say a hash function generates numbers from 0 to 2^32-1, and there are 1000 bits in your bloom filter:

```
int bit_index = hash_function(input_value) % 1000;
```

It's important to note here that 2^32-1 is massively greater than 1000.  Say the hash function instead generated pretty evenly distributed numbers but only between 0 and 1023 inclusive, then after the modulus operation it'd be twice as likely that bit_index would be in the 0..23 range as compared to 24..999 (because e.g. inputs 2 and 1002 both result in a post-modulus value of 2, but only an input of 25 produces an output of 25).  For that reason, if you have a hash function generating 32 bits, you might want to use a bloom filter sized to a number of bits that's a power of two, then slice out sections of the hash value to use as as if independent hash functions - all explained in the wikipedia article you link.  That requires a good quality hash function though, as any "clustering" flaws in the hash function will be passed through unmitigated to the output; having a prime number of bits is one way to mitigate such poor hashing.  Still, with good hash functions, powers of two also make it easy to extract bit indices using bitwise AND operations and - if needed - bit shifting, which can be faster than integer modulus, though the hash functions are probably going to dwarf that consideration in the overall performance profile.

Edit - addressing comments...

Assuming your MD5 function's returning an `unsigned char*` "p" to `MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH` bytes of data, I suggested you try:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH >= sizeof(int));
int bit_index = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(p) % num_of_bloom_filter_bits;
```

That was actually *a particularly bad idea* - sorry - I'll explain the two reasons why in a moment.  First, to answer your question about what it does: `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT()` is designed to give you a compile error if the expression it's passed has evaluated to `false`.  Here, it's basically a way of documenting the requirement that `MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH` - which is the size in characters of the textual representation of the MD5 hash - be at least as long as the number of bytes your system uses for an `int` integer type.  (That size is probably 4 bytes, but might be 8.)  That requirement is intended to ensure that the `reinterpret_cast` in the next line is safe.  What that does is read a value from the bytes at the start of the textual representation of the MD5 hash as if those bytes contained an `int`.  So, say your `int` size *is* 4, MD5 hash is "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661" as in your comment: the first 4 bytes contain "0cc1".  The ASCII codes for that text are 48, 99, 99, 49 decimal.  When they're read into an `int`, depending on the endianness of the CPU the value could differ, but basically you'll get one of those numbers times 256^3 plus another one times 256^2 plus a third times 256 plus the final number.

The reasons I said this was a particularly bad idea are:

- each character in the MD5 string is either a digit (ASCII codes 48-57) or a letter from "a" through "f" (97-102).  Those 16 values are ony a 16th of the variation that a byte can have, and while the `int` value you generate occupies 32 bits you really only get 2^16 distinct values.
- on some computers, `int`s must be aligned at a memory address that's a multiple of 2, 4, 8 etc..  The `reinterpret_cast` - if the text happens to start at an incompatible address, could crash your computer.  Note: Intel & AMDs have no such alignment requirement, though it may be faster for them to operate on properly aligned data.

So, another suggestion:

```
// create a buffer of the right size to hold a valid unsigned long in hex representation...
char data[sizeof(unsigned long) * 2 + 1];

// copy as much of the md5 text as will fit into the buffer, NUL terminating it...
sprintf(data, "%.*s", sizeof data - 1, md5);

// convert to an unsigned long...
m = strtoul(data, /*endptr*/ NULL, /*base*/ 16);
```

Here, if the md5 representation was shorter than the data buffer, just the initial part of it would be safely copied, so the BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT isn't required.

It's much easier to use a non-cryptographic hash function, as they'll generally just return you a number rather than a readble text buffer representation of the number, so you can avoid all this nonsense.

Comment: If I use MD5 hash function which outputs 32bits, how can I get the index of the bloomfilter from it? suppose MD5 ("a")=0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661, here how can I get bitindex from it which is actually an integer?

Comment: Assuming your MD5 function's returning an `unsigned char*` "`p`" to `MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH` bytes of data, you can try `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH >= sizeof(int)); int bit_index = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(p) % num_of_bloom_filter_bits;`.

Comment: Separately - MD5 may be overkill... there's some simpler/faster algos described at http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html (with C++ implementations linked) that were recommended elsewhere though I've not used them personally.

Comment: Thanks a lot tony for letting me know about the other hash functions which I was badly in need of! Would you mind explaining a bit what actually is going on when I am applying the above code block that you wrote for converting MD5 output to bloomfilter index? I tested your code which actually gives me a value within the range of number of bloom filter bits, but I am missing the part how it actually works,my apologies I am also not familiar with boost library,would you please tell me why you used it here?

Comment: Well - that's a big enough question that I'll edit a discussion into my answer....

Comment: Ok, it seems that the 32 bits MD5 output can be sliced into 8 chunks which can then be used as independent hashes,If im not wrong.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK: the MD5 output you list above ("0cc1...2661") has 32 hexadecimal digits, and a hexadecimal digit has 16 values so is equivalent to 4 binary digits (0000 binary = 0 hex, 1111 binary = f hex).  So, your MD5 hash is 128 bits long.  You can slice that into as many chunks as you like, but you want each chunk to have at least enough distinct values as your bloom filter has bits.  For example, if you use a 1000 bit bloom filter, you need 10 bits of high quality hash to choose a unique bloom filter bit, so you can extract 12 different hash values from the MD5 hash.