# Converting Hash Function Values to Integer Values which can be used in Bloom Filter of m bits Range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, bloom-filter

Here's some Basic about [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

Can anyone explain to me how can we convert a  hash function( lets say md5,sha1 or any other pre-defined Hash function) to Integer Value in Range 0 to m where m is the bit-range of Bloom Filter.

I want to know how can we get the value from hash function in a defined range which i can use to index in bloom filters.

Till know i have refered:

1.[Using hash functions with Bloom filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753467/using-hash-functions-with-bloom-filters),

2.[How to map hashfunction output to bloomfilter indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680074/how-to-map-hashfunction-output-to-bloomfilter-indices)
and

http://billmill.org/bloomfilter-tutorial/

But in all these there is no example given and in the last one they have used javascript and in that `Jenkins 96 bit mix function` and 2 hash functions `fnv` and `murmur`, which is quite Complex to understand.

What i understood is we divide the hash function value e.g: using md5 `"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"` and we divide it in chunks of 4bits or any bit number of chunks for 4 bit division we do "0cc1","75b9" but what after that?

I couldn't understand what we do after this step and how we set the range so that it should not be greater than the ARRAY size of Bloom Filter.

Can anybody provide me a live basic example  in php or c++ language?

I know md5 is not a function which you should in bloom filters but i just need to understand the concept how we do it.

Comment: If it's a good hash function, just use the lowest (or highest) M bits. FNV is probably not good enough for that. MD5 and murmur and certainly SHA1 are. Why do you think MD5 shouldn't be used?

Comment: hii lee , thanks for your reply, I have read somewhere that md5 produces too many keys and for a small bloom filter say `1000` bit bloom filters it creates some problems because it forms 2^32-1 bit Values which is quite larger than 1000 so we have to use modulus % to decrease that value. Do you have a live example of how we map index and within the range of bloom filter?

Comment: Well, yeah, that just makes it inefficient, not unsuitable.